# I want sync salesforce objects and my web application. How?

Tags: custom-object, integration, controller, standardcontroller, sync

How to sync salesforce custom objects and my web application? I already tried that but I am fully confused with that.

Please tell me how can I proceed ?

Comment: what did you try so far? which application initiates the sync - Salesforce or your web application?

Comment: Lets give the OP a chance to improve the question. At least it represents a common requirement which is very often underestimated in respect of cost and complexity in projects. Possibly the given overview of general options might be enough to point him or her to a direction.

Comment: @ravishramananda you should hurry to improve your question or it will be most likely closed. At least you should name you web app and provide some details about what you plan.

Comment: This is indeed a very broad question. Consider that you first need to know the possibilities of integration, design a synchronization process depending on your business processes/application and than set up integration through native funcitonalities or middle-ware tools.  Currently you're asking us "how do i build a house ?" while that's nearly impossible to answer. You have to do some work and break down your problem to sub-problems like "What type of screws do I need to attach a door to my house".

Comment: I am closing this question, but you can still update/edit it to be around a specific issue and request it to be re-opend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to give a general answer. You don't tell us which web application you are talking about and what scope you have in mind (which custom objects/fields in detail? Relationshipts? Oneway or bidirectional? etc).

**APP**

Data-integration is a tough task and you should be very experienced to do it - unless of course you find an app on AppExchange ( https://appexchange.salesforce.com/ ) which covers your requirements out of the box. That's why it would help that you name your *incognito web* app. Maybe people here can point you to an app which fits.

**API**

If for your *incognito web app* there is no integration-app on the AppExchange, next best thing would be to check for possible APIs and Interfaces. On the side of salesforce you will find a rich choice of different APIs for almost all flavors (SOAP, REST, Bulk, Streaming, just to name some).

**ETL**

An other approach would be to use ETL processes on the database-level. Thereforce I would recommend not to use tools like dataloader, but to start with more enhanced things like Talend (https://www.talend.com/) - it's openscource, free and powerful.